# Android: Compilation error with v7 support lib 27.1.0 "Program type already present" android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, listadapter, dex

I think there must be a bug with the 27.1.0 v7 support lib, [just released](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html). After updating my project to use it (from 26.1.0), I keep getting this compilation error:

> **Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRegularDebug FAILED
>   D8 is used to merge dex.
>   Program type already present: android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter**
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRegularDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter
> - Try:
>     Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRegularDebug'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter
>         at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>         at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>         ... 29 more
>     Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:230)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
>         at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>         ... 41 more
>     Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter
>         at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:61)
>         at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
>         at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
>         at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexApplication$Builder.build(DexApplication.java:408)
>         at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:96)
>         at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:179)
>         at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:152)
>         at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:71)
>         at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:73)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:35)

I have looked at my project's dependencies (with `./gradlew :<module>:dependencies` [where `<module>` is all my modules]) and verified that I have only *one* dependency that should be pulling in the support [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html) class, and it is this one:

```
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0"
```

I also use

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        ...
        force "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0"
    }
}
```

I have tried cleaning/rebuilding. I have tried invalidating caches and restarting. I have also tried manually deleting all my build folders and `.gradle` folders. I have also tried disabling D8, but then my build just hangs forever. The problem persists. I'm not even *using* `ListAdapter`!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out the **android.arch.paging:runtime-1.0.0-alpha4-1** dependency *also* had `ListAdapter` declared. After updating the paging lib to **alpha6**, the problem was resolved.

**EDIT** For some reason, this question is getting a lot of attention! So, I thought I'd add this comment as a "teach a person to fish" sort of moment. The question: how did I figure out where my `ListAdapter`s were coming from? The answer? If you're using Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to begin searching for class names. You'll see this dialog:

[image]

Please note the checkbox! If you don't have that checked, you will *never* find a class included by a library. With it checked, it'll show the provenance of every class in your project.

Comment: Life super duper saver ! How come upgrading the arch dependency solved it? Does it not declare the class anymore or what else could be the reason?

Comment: @Raymond232 I can only assume Google decided to rearrange which artifacts had which classes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply updating all my dependencies, cleaning and rebuilding the project did the trick for me. I think there's some kind of dependency/library conflict going on. An outdated library may be trying to use an older version of support library while you are trying to use a newer version somewhere else.