# Build Fails with error: cannot find symbol class SupportSQLiteDatabase although dependencies are included

Tags: android, android-multidex

Working on an Android app. The app was working fine, but suddenly I am getting build fails, with multiple 'cannot find symbol class' errors. I am pretty sure I have pushed several build releases on the same code, which is giving cannot find class errors now.

Errors in classes for which I have already included the implementations in the gradle files. `(Error:(3, 35) error: cannot find symbol class SupportSQLiteDatabase)`, `(Error:(3, 35) error: cannot find symbol class SupportSQLiteQuery)`

Have tried changing `details.useVersion` to 28.0.0 but same result.

```
configurations.all 
{
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle entries:

```
android 
{
    compileSdkVersion 28

    //buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies 
{
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8+'
//    Barcode reader requires Version 8.1+ of playservices.
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Adding dependencies for the ROOM library
    //
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
    // alternatively, just ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
    // alternatively, just LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
    // Room (use 1.1.0-alpha1 for latest alpha)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    // Paging
    implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha5"
    // Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.0"
    // Test helpers for Room
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
    //
    //End ROOM library dependencies
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    //JSON GSON Depedency
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    //Volley Dependency for HTTP(s) requests
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    //Recycler view and card view
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    //ui Template related dependencies
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.10.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //Retrofit libraries
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

    //Firebase & Google Services
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'

    //RxJava libraries
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'

    //view injection
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // for dimension manage
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'

    //datepicker
    implementation 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.6'

    //Dependency for SupportSQLiteDatabase
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence:db:1.1.1'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried invalidating/restarting - Did not work. 
Removed Library files and sync with Gradle - did not work.

Upgraded Android Studio to 3.3.2. Used Kotlin V 1.3. Upgraded Gradle. 
That removed the 'cannot find symbol class' error. But gave me new errors. 
For some reason AndroidManifest.xml was throwing errors for the following format :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".transactions.xxx.xxx"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

But when the same code was changed to

```
    <activity
        android:name=".transactions.xxx.xxx"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

It worked fine.

Finally I got 'program type already present : ...ListAdapter' error which was resolved by

[Android: Compilation error with v7 support lib 27.1.0 "Program type already present" android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038630/android-compilation-error-with-v7-support-lib-27-1-0-program-type-already-pres)